# Replacing characters with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

thanks in advance for your help.

I'm using this piece of code to replace a circumflex a that keeps appearing in a website I'm working on, however it only replaces the first occurance of the circumflex a in a given tag.

Can anyone help me extend the code?

```
    $(function() {
    $('h2, h3, h4, p, a, div, body').each(function() {
        var $h = $(this);
        var html = $h.html();
        html = html.replace( 'Â', '' );
        $h.html( html );
    });
})
```

Comment: How could an Â "keep appearing"? It sounds like you might have encoding issues.

Comment: It's a movable type 5 installation, the script that creates/upgrades the database seems to do so with the wrong encoding so whenever a £ sign appears in the code a circumflex a precedes it. The DB people working on a fix but in the meantime I've had to correct the problem on the front end in what remains a crappy but successful way. Wish it were otherwise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the "/g" global indicator to your regular expression:

```
html = html.replace( /Â/g, '' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html = html.replace(/Â/g, '');
```